# Getting a value from xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have a xml from url [xml](http://server5.onlinegpstracker.com/xml_files/2501_group_summary.xml)

I get the xml to my android application. But i dont know how to get a specified value from xml. I need to get geopoint inside "ReportBody" where index=1. I am attaching my java code below. Thanks in advance for any positive help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String xml;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Connection().execute();
}
private class Connection extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://server5.onlinegpstracker.com/xml_files/2501_group_summary.xml");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return xml;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Parse XML data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml)

Answer (score 0):

when you get the xml from url as string than you should parse it to java object with the help of xml parser libraries you can do this for more information visit this link :

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml